# mysql Как правильно реализовать похожие запросы с разным условием

Tags: mysql

Нужно из 1 таблицы взять данные для 4 блоков с разным условием!

Пример:

```
select u_id, u_name WHERE u_active = 1 AND u_date > NOW() LIMIT 10 // для 1 блока
select u_id, u_name WHERE u_active = 1 AND u_date < NOW() LIMIT 10 // для 2 блока
select u_id, u_name WHERE u_active = 0 AND u_date > NOW() LIMIT 10 // для 3 блока
select u_id, u_name WHERE u_active = 0 AND u_date < NOW() LIMIT 10 // для 4 блока
```

Вопросы:

1. Делать отдельные запросы для каждого блока или брать сразу все через UNION? или еще есть какой-то вариант?
2. На другой странице нужны только 1 и 2 блок (то есть только первые два запроса). Создать 2 функции 1 будет делать 4 запроса, а для другой сраницы другая функция которая будет делать 2 запроса?

Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Судя по запросам вы хотите получить по факту всю таблицу из БД, только разделенную на 4 части. Это так ? В принципе можно сделать один select и отсортировать по убыванию u_active и даты, а блоки начинать когда через границу условий переходит

Comment: либо добавить столбец с `case` возвращающий идентификатор блока

Comment: @Mike будет LIMIT в каждом запросе

Comment: В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @bsbak А почему вы в вопросе про лимиты ничего не указали ? Это в корне меняет задачу

Comment: Писал на скорую руку, забыл написать...Вопрос изменил.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u_id, 
   u_name,
   case when u_active = 1 AND u_date > NOW() then '1 block'
        when u_active = 1 AND u_date < NOW() then '2 block'
        when u_active = 0 AND u_date > NOW() then '3 block'
        when u_active = 0 AND u_date < NOW() then '4 block' end as block
from table
```

Comment: Можно просто `SELECT ..., (u_active=1)*2+(u_date > NOW()) AS block ...`